# Relabelling large amounts of data in Excel

Tags: excel

In a CSV file: I want to relabel 433,000+ rows of IDs that look like "e904ab64a642efcd25f4a43cb729701646d4bf7a4ed0bacbae9d85127978606a" into simpler ID codes. For each of these unique IDs there are 4-5 rows of data. I really don't want to "find and replace" each of them because there are over 2000+ unique IDs. Is there any function in excel that can help me do that? Otherwise, any recommendations of what programs I can use?

Comment: Do you have a list of unique IDs? If yes, you can use a script to loop through them and do a replace. This could be done in Excel or a good text editor

Comment: Is there an alogrithm that determines how things are reduced? For example, abctttttttttt123 is reduced to abc123?

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs are always on consecutive lines, you can

1. Store the ID before replacement
2. replace it with your simpler ID (also store it)
3. go to next line
4. check if the ID is the same as stored on the previous line

   If yes, use the same replacement ID as on previous line

   If no, do same 1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy doing this manually (since your tags do not currently include [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)) then here is a simple approach:

1. Create a Unique List of IDs, for example by creating a 1-column
   PivotTable
2. Next to each Unique ID, put your *simplified ID* (however you are creating that - is there an algorithm, or could it just be `=Row()`?)
3. Insert a column in the original sheet, adjacent to the ID column
4. Use a `VLOOKUP` to find the matching Simplified ID (e.g. `=VLOOKUP(A1,'New IDs'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`)
5. When it has finished calculating, copy the Simplified IDs, and Paste Special as Values